# jQuery UI Layout resizer bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, layout, user-interface

I am trying to use jQuery UI Layout Plug-in.
When I open simple demo (http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/simple.html
) from developer’s site, it looks perfect.
But if I run this demo (and any other Layout demo) from my local web server,some needless elements is displayed.

[screenshot](http://s17.postimage.org/l591c60gf/layout_err.jpg)
(I am novice user so I am not allowed to post images there)

I explored this page in Firebug and saw that it was the panel resizers (class="ui-layout-resizer”), displayed in a wrong place.

How can i fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This exact issue can be replicated by setting the CSS property `box-sizing` for the pane to anything other than `content-box`.

This issue seems present in the latest release candidate (1.3.0 – RC30.75).  Without knowing more details about your situation, I don't know if this affects you, however, here is a fix for this specific issue.

replace the `cssWidth` function (line 448 in RC30.75 non-minified, but this may change.  Watch out for the comma preceding the method name) with the following:

```
cssWidth: function ($E, outerWidth) {
        // a 'calculated' outerHeight can be passed so borders 
        // and/or padding are removed if needed
        if (outerWidth <= 0) return 0;

        if (!$.layout.browser.boxModel) return outerWidth;

        var b = $.layout.borderWidth
            ,   n = $.layout.cssNum
            ,   W = outerWidth

        // depending on the level of box-sizing used, strip 
        // padding and/or margins from the width
        var boxSizing = $E.css("box-sizing")

        if (boxSizing !== "border-box") {
            W = W - n($E, "paddingLeft")
                - n($E, "paddingRight");
            if (boxSizing !== "padding-box") {
                W = W - b($E, "Left")
                      - b($E, "Right");
            }
        }

        return max(0,W);
    }
```

I've submitted this edit to the group over there.  If I'm not doing something silly, and this does fix the problem to their satisfaction, then hopefully the changes will end up in the product.

Answer (score 0):

Other solution: set the box-sizing to "content-box".

---

For more detail, in source code of the lib, it was fixed in latest code 1.4.1 but there is another bug which disable the fix.

Code v.1.4.1:

```
    var lb  = $.layout.browser
    ,   bs  = !lb.boxModel ? "border-box" : lb.boxSizing ? $E.css("boxSizing") : "content-box"
    ,   b   = $.layout.borderWidth
    ,   n   = $.layout.cssNum
    ,   W   = outerWidth
    ;
    // strip border and/or padding from outerWidth to get CSS Width
    if (bs !== "border-box")
        W -= (b($E, "Left") + b($E, "Right"));
    if (bs === "content-box")
        W -= (n($E, "paddingLeft") + n($E, "paddingRight"));
```

BUT

```
bs = $s.boxSizing !== undefined ? $s.boxSizing : $s.boxSizingReliable
```

It's always false for chrome as $s.boxSizingReliable() => false.